# Unable to send sms to email and phone using twilio and python,django restframework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, twilio

I have registered with `twilio` and my phone number is also activated,I have used this `twilio` service in `django restframework` and trying to send SMS to phone and email, but that time getting error. Any solution

```
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: 
HTTP Error Your request was:

POST /Accounts/ACd554de003ceb5ec51587cf5b06219b5e/Messages.json
```

**Twilio returned the following information:**

Unable to create record:

The number  is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send messages to unverified numbers; verify  at `twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified`, or purchase a Twilio number to send messages to unverified numbers.

**More information may be available here:**

https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21608

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While you are using a trial account you are only able to send SMS messages to numbers that you have verified with your Twilio account. You can verify a number by [following these steps](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio):

> - Login to your account at https://www.twilio.com/console.
> - Click Phone Numbers.
> - Click [Verified Caller IDs](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified).
> - Click the red + sign icon.
> - Enter the desired phone number to verify, and then click Call Me.
> - NOTE: Click Text you instead to receive a text message for verification.

Once you have verified your number you should be able to send an SMS from a Twilio number that you bought in the console to your number using the API.

You also said you were "trying to send SMS to phone and **email**". You cannot send an SMS to an email address using the [Messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource). If you want to send emails, I would look into [the SendGrid API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html).